# Splat Unpacking a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to unpack a list:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
a, *b = ls
```

Then, I tried to unpack a dictionary:

```
dc = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
a, **b = dc
# Out: SyntaxError
```

I was expecting this to work...

This is not a big deal since I can still get the keys (`a, *b = dc`), the values (`a_val, *b_val = dc.values()`) and zip them into a dictionary. But I'm curious: am I missing something here? Will this be possible in the future?

By the way, I'm using Python 3.6, where a dictionary is not yet guaranteed to be ordered but even using [collection.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) the unpacking doesn't work.

Comment: What would you expect the value of `a` and `b` to be after doing that?

Comment: Personal opinion: I would expect this to work in future versions of Python. In general splat-unpacking has been becoming more commonplace and getting more feature complete.

Comment: @BrenBarn I would expect `b = {'y': 2, 'z':3}` (assuming `a, *b = dc` gives `a = 'x', b = ['y', 'z']`)

Comment: It seems strange though to be iterating over the keys and the items in different parts of the same assignment.  I can see iterating over either one, but not both at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem is ordering. Since dictionaries are unordered, it's easy to produce values that introduce subtle bugs in code that seems like it should work.

```
dc = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
a, *b = dc
# `a` could be any of 'x', 'y', 'z'
a2, **b2 = dc
# `a2` could be any of {'x': 1}, {'y': 2}, {'z': 3}
# (though I believe it's constrained to be the same key as `a` above)
```

Comment: Dictionaries are actually ordered! Guido said it will be guaranteed in all future versions a few weeks ago. Ordered by insertion order, that is.

Comment: @jhpratt What?? For all Python versions? Because I'd think that breaks implementations other than CPython..... Do you have a link handy?

Comment: Future versions (>3.7). I saw it on Raymond Hettinger's Twitter, though I'm on mobile so I can't dig it up now.

Comment: @jhpratt So CPython only, then. That makes this syntax...problematic :D

Comment: Yeah, Guido isn't BDFL for PyPy

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I'm reading the comment thread on @raymondh now too. Doesn't really change my answer, though -- it's only required per language spec in 3.7+, and happens to work due to implementation on CPython 3.6

Comment: Of course. Was just a side note when you mentioned they're unordered.